# Login using fingerprint only ? Is it possible?

Tags: android, ios, sensors, fingerprint

Is it possible to store users fingerprints in a cloud? Im thinking about an app that needs onyl fingerprint to log in. Is it possible ?

Comment: Because of security reasons you cannot access the fingerprint of the user directly - I for one wouldn't like apps storing my fingerprint in some closed-source cloud. But you may hash values using the fingerprint provided by the user. For that read the documentation.

Comment: You're asking two different questions. _Can you have a login functionality that depends only on fingerprint authentication?_ Yes, you can. _Is it possible to store the users' fingerprints in the cloud?_ No, it is not, because you don't have access to the actual fingerprints or any derivates thereof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to login using finger prints only.

- A serialized scanned fingerprint object is output as a byteArrayOutputStream using ObjectOutputStream.
- The output is then encoded to base64 and sent as HTTP port to a
  provided server URL().
- To serialize an object means a Java object is represented as a
  sequence of bytes that includes the object's data as well as
  information about the object's type and the types of data stored in
  the object.
- The server endpoint receives the base64 bytearray, decodes it into a
  plain byteArray and then casts it to a libfprint object using
  objectinputStream.
- This libfprint object is then compared to existing instances stored
  in the database in your cloud.
- DURING matching, the libfprint object is compared with the
  finger already stored. If any of the three binary data
  (stored prints) has an integer value above the set threshold (70),
  the user is identified and thus is considered a true match,
  otherwise the bozorth matching algorithm assumes the finger does not
  exist in the database and hence prompts for a new enrollment.
- Bozorth    is a fingerprint matching algorithm which is minutiae
  based, It does    both one-to-one and one-to-many matching
  operations.
- The recommended bozorth threshold is an integer of 40, however in my
  tests with the threshold at 40 oftenly produced false positives. A
  false positive happens when a user is wrongly identified as the
  owner of the fingerprint. We settled on the approach to enroll the
  same finger three times during new registration and increase the
  matching threshold to 70.
- Verification algorithm compares the currently captured fingerprint image to each users three instances stored in the database. The user is identified positively if any of the three instances return a match value of more than 70.